# How can I get modifed/deleted records from a stored procedure in ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I am making a little test tool for stored procedures in our SQL Server. I can compare their results easily but I need to compare their modified records too. Is it possible with standard ADO.NET components?

Answer (score 1):

Use the OUTPUT clause on the DML in the stored procedure to return the affected rows back to client:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx